# .net substring not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, substring

I'm getting an ArgumentOutOfRange error when using substring function in .NET.  I'm new to .NET so probably doing something wrong.  I have a txtField, which is a text field component in GUI.  I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express

```
txtField.Substring(txtField.Length-4,txtField.Length-1)
```

If txt.Field contains only numberic values it works ok, but as soon as the text field contains characters it breaks.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET takes the length of the substring as the second parameter, not the end (exclusive).  So if you want three characters, do:

```
txtField.Substring(txtField.Length-4, 3)
```

Comment: Yup silly me...I actually looked at the API but interpreted it wrong.